# Show posts from specific user only ? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I've managed to find the below snippet which hides all posts excepts the ones made by the current user when added to functions.php
However, I want to make this also allow posts from a specific user ID, particularly the admin posts in order to enable the normal Blog to be visible. I'm not sure how I can achieve that.

P.S. I have zero programming knowledge and while I can kind of get what this does I'm unable to expand it since I don't know the proper formatting...

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wptw_query_disable_post_media' );
function wptw_query_disable_post_media( $wp_query ) {
 global $current_user;
 if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
    $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
    add_filter('views_edit-post', 'wptw_show_post_counts');
    add_filter('views_upload', 'wptw_show_media_counts');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did the most basic thing possible. Just duplicated the code above, renaming the function and replacing "$current_user->ID" with just the ID of the user I wanted (in this case 12.) So the code for including one more user's posts looks like this:

```html
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_admin_posts' );
function show_admin_posts( $wp_query  ) {
 global $current_user;
 if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
    $wp_query->set( 'author', 12);
    
 }
}
```

Comment: Update: I actually managed to bypass this using Elementor and the Premium Addons for Elementor plugin (which is free) to create a custom blog page. When using elementor to select the blog categories they become visible to everyone, while the pages that use the theme's post listing only show the current user's posts.
So there is no need to duplicate this code, and can only use it with ('author', $current_user-ID) arguments